# command cursor' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo

I'm new in Python and MongoDB and I am starting a new project with flask-python and MongoDB. When I try returning data using the `aggregate()` function, it gives me the following error:

> command cursor' object is not subscriptable.

Here is my code for the query:

```
Data = db.mytable.aggregate([ { "$group": {"_id": "$Name" ,"count": { "$sum": 1 }}}])
return Data['result']
```

I also changed this:

```
Data = db.mytable.aggregate([ { "$group": {"_id": "$Name" ,"count": { "$sum": 1 }}}],userCursor= False)
```

but it gives me the following error:

> error.pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: command SON([('aggregate', 'mytable'), ('pipeline', [{'$group': {'_id': '$Name', 'count': {'$sum': 1}}}]), ('useCursor', False)]) on namespace mydb.$cmd failed: unrecognized field 'useCursor

Note: I am using MongoDB 3.2 and Python3

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since Pymongo 3.0, the [`.aggregate()`](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.aggregate) method return a [CommandCursor](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/command_cursor.html#pymongo.command_cursor.CommandCursor) which doesn't implement the [`__getitem__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) method. Instead I suggest you return the `cursor` object in your function/method or turn to result into a list like this: `return list(Data)`

Comment: but i am return list(Data) its give value  ['waitedMS', 'ok', 'result']

Comment: This only happens in version prior to 3.0 in which case `Data['result']` works fine. What Pymongo version are you on?

Comment: i am using pymongo 2.8

Comment: it there way to return the dict directly ? 3.4 version